# how to remove the slashes from json key while converting object into string

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to convert JSON object into string by doing the below

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
            object.put("video", data);
            array1.add( object.toString().replace("\\\\"," "));
```

Actual result

```
["{\"photos\":\"/contests/1/images/1.png\"}", 
{\"photos\":\"/contests/1/images/2.png\"}"]
```

Expected result

```
["{"photos":"/contests/1/images/1.png\"}"," 
{"photos":"/contests/1/images/2.png\"}"]
```

not able to remove the slashes from key

Comment: From which package `JSONObject` class comes from?

Answer (score 0):

Use `replaceAll` instead of `replace`

```
replaceAll("\\\\", "")
```

Comment: tried this, object.toString().replaceAll("\\\\","")); not working still getting the same

Answer (score 0):

When you want to replace all the occurences with `.replace`, the first parameter must be a regex, if you supply a string, only the first occurrence will be replaced, that's why your replace wouldn't work.

Please use:
`.replace("/\\/g","")`

Alternatively, `replaceAll` can be used as @Code_Mono suggested

Answer (score 0):

The Code_Mode mentioned is correct one.

Because String is immutable. Make sure that you put it right place.

You can refer code bellow for more detail:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String json = "[\"{\\\"photos\\\":\\\"/contests/1/images/1.png\\\"}\", {\\\"photos\\\":\\\"/contests/1/images/2.png\\\"}\"]";
        json.replaceAll("\\\\","");
        System.out.println(json);

        String jsonReplace = json.replaceAll("\\\\","");
        System.out.println(jsonReplace);
    }
```

Output value:

```
["{\"photos\":\"/contests/1/images/1.png\"}", {\"photos\":\"/contests/1/images/2.png\"}"]
["{"photos":"/contests/1/images/1.png"}", {"photos":"/contests/1/images/2.png"}"]
```